# Does TechTool Deluxe still come with AppleCare?

Tags: software, applecare

I have always purchased AppleCare with new Macs, and I seem to recall TechTool Deluxe being an important part of the bundle. I bought an iMac at the beginning of the year and neglected to pop in the AppleCare DVD at that time since I knew I was already registered for support and the TT app was migrated from my old computer.

However, today when I got the urge to investigate some drive integrity issues, the migrated version of TT wasn't compatible with the current OS and I couldn't seem to find my AppleCare DVD. Some Google searching shows that as recent as last December, the app was available for download from apple.com, however, those links are now dead and [Apple's product page](http://www.apple.com/support/products/mac.html) makes no mention of TechTool Deluxe whatsoever. (Micromat's [own website](http://www.micromat.com/index.php?Itemid=51&id=37&option=com_content&task=view) has a sneaky past-tense "was" in their product description now.

So, what's the low-down? When did the bundle expire--did the AppleCare I purchased in January contain this on the DVD? Am I screwed if I can't find that DVD, or are there other download options? Any reasons I might *not* want to use that software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's all the details:

http://www.macgasm.net/2011/03/03/tech-tool-deluxe-longer-included-applecare/

I totally agree with their recommendation of Drive Genius and Disk Warrior. I use them daily and could not do my job without them.

Comment: What do you do to your computer that requires daily use of *two* disk repair tools on a daily basis?

Comment: I manage an Apple Authorized Service Provider location. We work on different machines daily that are in and out of warranty and these tools plus others are great.